# PHP 8 Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

Tags: php, linux, laravel, openssl

I have recently run into an issue with my Laravel setup which I can't figure out. Out of nowhere, whenever I load my site I am getting an error;

```php
    Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()
```

The function is being called from `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php:85`

I have tried a lot of fixes that have been posted on SO with no change. for instance `composer install` `composer update`

I have loaded `00_openssl.ini` in my `/etc/php8/conf.d` directory, and the contents of which are

```
extension=openssl.so
```

The modules which are loaded are as follows;

```
/etc/php8/conf.d # php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
gd
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
Zend OPcache
```

If I look through my php.ini file for OpenSSL I get the following;

```
/etc/php8/conf.d # php -i | grep openssl
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl' '--host=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl' '--prefix=/usr' '--program-suffix=8' '--libdir=/usr/lib/php8' '--datadir=/usr/share/php8' '--sysconfdir=/etc/php8' '--localstatedir=/var' '--with-layout=GNU' '--with-pic' '--with-pear=/usr/share/php8' '--with-config-file-path=/etc/php8' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php8/conf.d' '--disable-short-tags' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--with-bz2=shared' '--enable-calendar=shared' '--enable-ctype=shared' '--with-curl=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-dbmaker=shared' '--with-gdbm' '--with-lmdb' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-enchant=shared' '--enable-exif=shared' '--with-ffi=shared' '--enable-fileinfo=shared' '--enable-ftp=shared' '--enable-gd=shared' '--with-freetype' '--with-jpeg' '--with-webp' '--with-xpm' '--disable-gd-jis-conv' '--with-gettext=shared' '--with-gmp=shared' '--with-iconv=shared' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-intl=shared' '--with-kerberos' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-libedit' '--with-libxml' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--with-mysqli=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' '--enable-mysqlnd=shared' '--enable-opcache=shared' '--with-openssl=shared' '--with-system-ciphers' '--with-password-argon2' '--enable-pcntl=shared' '--with-external-pcre' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--with-pdo-dblib=shared' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-odbc=shared,unixODBC,/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-phar=shared' '--enable-posix=shared' '--with-pspell=shared' '--without-readline' '--enable-session=shared' '--enable-shmop=shared' '--enable-simplexml=shared' '--with-snmp=shared' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-sodium=shared' '--enable-sockets=shared' '--with-sqlite3=shared' '--enable-sysvmsg=shared' '--enable-sysvsem=shared' '--enable-sysvshm=shared' '--with-tidy=shared' '--enable-tokenizer=shared' '--with-unixODBC=shared,/usr' '--enable-xml=shared' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared' '--with-xsl=shared' '--with-zip=shared' '--with-zlib' '--disable-phpdbg' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-embed' '--enable-litespeed' 'build_alias=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl' 'host_alias=x86_64-alpine-linux-musl'
Openssl default config => /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
```

Nothing I do fixes the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the extension directory is correct and that it's not commented out with a semicolon ';'

e.g.

```
extension_dir =  "C:/php/ext"
```